# How to print a tick/checkmark character on the same line as the string in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

So i have a string which i am reading from a file. I want to print a tick next to it if a certain condition is met in my program. How ever the tick if printed on the next line to the string. Here is the function responsible for printing the string.

```
def printData(self):
        spaces = " " * self.getLevel() * 4 + "|__"  if self.getLevel() != 0 else ""
        if self.completed:
            print(spaces + self.data + u'\u2713')

        else:
            print(spaces + self.data)

        for child in self.children:
            print(child.printData())
        return ""
```

In the above code, self.data is actually the string to be printed. I have an idea of why this is happening but dont know how to fix it. When i print out the list that contains the strings, it has new line characters attached the the end of every string, which might be forcing the ticks to  move to the next line. Heres how i am reading the data the the file.

```
def getCompData(self):
        with open("subdata.txt", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                if line[0] == "c":
                    self.compTopics.append(line[1:])

        return self.compTopics
```

I tried using `end=""` as follows but it doesent work either.

```
if self.completed:
    print(spaces + self.data, end="")
    print(u'\u2713')
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Could you please add sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be here in this function. The `readlines()` function keeps `\n` character at the end. To fix that problem, use `line.rstrip('\n')`. This should be your modified function:

```
def getCompData(self):
        with open("subdata.txt", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines:
                if line[0] == "c":
                    self.compTopics.append(line.rstrip('\n')[1:])

        return self.compTopics
```

This part works as expected now:

```
if self.completed:
    print(spaces + self.data, end="")
    print(u'\u2713')
```

Hopefully your function works as expected now :)